# Extending a jQuery plugin and accessing internal varaibles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I been looking for a solution for this with no success.
I am using a jQuery plugin and want to extend its functionality.

The plugin has a similar markup as this;

```
(function($) {
$.pluginToExtend = function (options) {
   var $foo = 'Hello', $bar = 'World';

   function fooBar( ){
      console.log('foo = '+foo+'. bar = '+bar+'.');
   }

   this.fooBar = fooBar;

}
})(jQuery)
```

I want to extend the plugin and access its internal values.
What I'm having trouble doing is accessing the internal values.
I'm having much troubling finding this answer.

I run;

```
var holder = $('#element').pluginToExtend( );

(function($) {
     holder = $.extend(holder, {
         extendedMethod: function(input){                   
                console.log(this); //logs the object correctly
                console.log(this.fooBar( )); //return the methods output correctly 
                console.log(this.foo); //undefined
                console.log(foo);//javascript error
           }
     })
 })(jQuery)

holder.extendedMethod( );
```

Why is it not possible for the extended method to access variables in the same way the other methods access them?
How can I access these variables?

Is there a better solution for this? Something I'm missing?

Comment: Variable scoping rules prevent accessing variables local to one function inside another function.

Comment: Local variables are not the same as object properties.

Comment: I suggest you read and digest Douglas Crockford's [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html), then you will better understand the issues.